# Punisher's "famous" quote

Tags: marvel, the-punisher

A famous quote attributed to Punisher is "God will judge our enemies / We'll arrange the meeting". Especially in merchandise like this:

[image]

Did he really say that? When?

Comment: I've seen this attributed to Schwarzkopf, the Marines in general, Special Forces. Snopes lists it as having been a phrase used in ROTC in the 80's (with no attribution), but I can't find anything other than the patches relating it to the Punisher.

Comment: Idk enough about the Punisher in the comics, but the logo has become heavily conflated witb U.S. special forces, especially Navy S.E.A.L.s, and particularly Chris Kyle, so my suspicion would be that this is a general military saying/quote just with the punisher logo (along the same lines as "you can run, but you'll just doe tired")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This phrase has been around in various forms for quite some time, so while I cannot find any evidence that the Punisher *did* say it, if he did it was not an original phrase to him.

The phrase as written has been [attributed to General Schwarzkopf](https://www.snopes.com/military/norman.asp) (Who oddly enough, did say something very similar a couple years after it was originally attributed to him), however it did not originate with him.

A similar phrase "To forgive the terrorists is up to God, to send them to him is up to me." was [attributed to Vladimir Putin](https://www.snopes.com/putin-forgive-terrorists-quote/), however this is also incorrect. Both of these articles reference a 1980's ROTC saying “Your enemy’s duty is to die in defense of his country. Your duty is to see that your enemy does his duty.”

The earliest sister phrase that I can find "Kill them all, let God sort them out" is [somewhat shakily attributed](http://www.thisdayinquotes.com/2011/07/kill-them-all-and-let-god-sort-them-out.html) to a French Cistercian monk named Arnaud Amalric (also variously referred to as Arnald Amalric and Arnauld-Amaury)

So the phrase and variations of it seem to be one of those anonymous things that get a jingoistic life of their own, and the Punisher logo attached for the bravura that goes with it.